# DWH Modeling Best Practices: Date Key Used by 2 Dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse

I am doing a course in BI development, and in order to solidify all the skills I have learned so far, I start a hands-on project (DWH design, ETL application, Data modeling and etc).

During the DWH design, I have encountered a dilemma, so I would appreciate getting some best practices from more experienced pros.

It got 2 dimension tables:

- DimWeather - a table that stores weather data. Each row is a day. The primary key is, of course, the date of the corresponding day.
- DimDate - a simple calendar table. The Primary key, in this case, is also a date.

Both tables are connected to a Fact table that stores a bike rental log.

Following DWH design best practices, I need to create a surrogate key - let's call it DateKey for both of the tables.

I am wondering, how to execute it in this situation?

To the best of my knowledge, the surrogate key for each table has to be unique but on the other hand this surrogate key has the same logic.

I would be glad to hear what you will do?

Thanks a lot for putting time and effort

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, DimWeather should be a fact table, if it stores measures and numerical data about the weather on specific date (temperature, air pressure, humidity, etc.) and dateID in this table should reference to "regular" DimDate table.

By definition, dimension tables should contain different attributes/hierarchies in order to put measures from fact table in specific context (time, location, demography, etc.). In your scenario, you would put weather measures in specific context (i.e. AVG temperature in NYC in February 2020; MAX humidity in LA in December 2019, etc. depending of the structure of your Weather table).

Other than that, surrogate key is just a non-meaning value (usually integer value with identity feature, to secure uniqueness of the key), EXCEPT for DimDate dimension, where you can give surrogate key meaning with creating integer values based on date value (for example: 20200311 for '2020-03-11'). Of course, it's not forbidden to use source primary key as a key in dimension table, but it's a bad practice, since it can happen that you have same value in different source systems and that can cause problems when you load data into DWH.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.
I also had a feeling that the weather table is naturally a FACT rather them DIM. In this case what are the best practices to work 2 FACT tables (an atypical architecture)?

Comment: Hi, I wouldn't say that it"s atypical to have 2 or more fact tables within one data model. I saw many cases when having multiple fact tables completely makes sense. For example, you can have fact table for each business process (in your scenario, one for weather figures, other for rental logs) and using conformed dimensions to put numbers in specific context. You can also have two fact tables for same business process, but using different granularity (imagine that you create one fact table with data aggregated on month level and other on daily level). Hope that it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Your explanation sounds logical and I will pursue it.
In this case, how would I craft the keys for the tables?
DimDate table - Primary key would be a Datekey (date surrogate key) as you suggested
FactWeather - logically the primary should also be the date. In this case, how do I create a surrogate that won't be the same as the one of DimDate. 

What is the best practice when two tables have logically the same PK logic?
What comes to my mind, is an arbitrary string as PK for FactWeather that would connect it to FaceBikeRentals.